# Waiting for asynchronous response from a chained sequelize function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am new to the asynchronous and web application development and i cannot figure out a way to return data from a function before my page is rendered. Also new to sequelize and any feedback on formatting or best practices is appreciated.

I have tried setting this function as a route which in fact does return data if i send it as a response res.send(recipes). But i want it to act as a function that i can call before my page gets rendered

getRecipes.js

```
const sequelized = require('sequelize'); 
const op = sequelized.Op;

async function getRecipes(){
    //SELECT * FROM ingredients
    ingredients.findAll({ 
        where: {}, 
        raw : true 
    }) 
    .then(ingredients_result =>{ 
        //Get ingredient that expires soon
        //Find recipes of the ingredient that expires soon
        recipe_ingredient.findAll({ 
            where: {}, 
            raw: true 
        }) 
        .then(recipe_ingrdient_result =>{ 
            //If we have all ingredients for a recipe then find name of that recipe by ID
            recipes.findAll({ 
                where: {recipe_id: {[op.in]: suggested_recipes}} 
            }) 
            .then(recipes =>{
                someinfo = JSON.stringify(recipes);
                // This is where i need the date to be returned from
                return someinfo; // But every time i load a page this returns undefined
            }) 
        })
    })
}

module.exports.getRecipes = getRecipes;
```

routes/user.js

```
const getStuff = require('./getRecipes');
router.get('/dashboard', async function(req, res){
    //This returns undefined
    var r_name = await getStuff.getRecipes();
    res.render('dashboard',{
            title:"Dashboard",
        });
    })
```

I am probably misunderstanding how async works, so any help would be appreciated! I know want to be able to retrieve results by running getRecipes function before the page gets rendered.

Comment: `getRecipes` isn't returning anything. Change to `return ingredients.findAll...` and also `return recipe_ingredient.findAll...` (and try to avoid the promise-as-callback antipattern)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: This is not a dupe. *I am probably misunderstanding how async works* - you have problems with promises first of all. You don't chain promises properly. Always return from `then`. Don't nest `then` unless this is necessary. You also don't handle errors in a middleware.

Comment: I understand this might be simple for some of you but switching from synchronous to non synchronous is kind of not easy, yet thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , if you have made the function the `async` then use it ( **[DO READ](https://javascript.info/async-await)** ):

This is how you should use `async/await` in your code :

```
async function getRecipes() {
    //SELECT * FROM ingredients
    let ingredients_result = await ingredients.findAll({ // <------- CHANGE IS HERE
        where: {},
        raw: true
    });

    //Get ingredient that expires soon
    //Find recipes of the ingredient that expires soon
    let recipe_ingrdient_result = await recipe_ingredient.findAll({ // <------- CHANGE IS HERE
        where: {},
        raw: true
    });

    //If we have all ingredients for a recipe then find name of that recipe by ID
    let recipes_result = await recipes.findAll({ // <------- CHANGE IS HERE
        where: {
            recipe_id: {
                [op.in]: suggested_recipes
            }
        }
    })

    let someinfo = JSON.stringify(recipes_result);
    return someinfo; 
}
```